# No session bound to the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I followed this tutorial: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/03/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps.aspx

I am not getting a 'no session bound to the current context' error when trying to load a page (mvc 3).

```
public static ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory()
        {

            return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008 // 
                              .ConnectionString(@"Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=db1;Uid=dev;Pwd=123;")
                              .ShowSql())
                //.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web"))
                //.CurrentSessionContext<CallSessionContext>()             
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                                   .AddFromAssemblyOf<User>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                                                .Create(false, false))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
        }
```

The actual error is in my Repository.cs file:

Line 114:        public virtual T Get(int id)
Line 115:        {
Line 116:            return _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().Get(id);
Line 117:        }
Line 118:

When I was debugging it, _sessionFactory wasn't null or anything, it just can't seem to find the bound session.

I have the httpmodule wired up in my web.config, and it does get run so that's not the problem.

In my nhibernate configuration, I tried both:

```
.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web"))
```

and

```
.CurrentSessionContext<CallSessionContext>()
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: When you say "In my nhibernate configuration, I tried both:", the examples you give are both the same. Could you edit your question to give the other configuration you tried! ^^

Comment: also try to set a breakpoint inside the `CurrentSession()` and `Bind(` methods, to make sure that they're being invoked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you are not binding your session to the context.  Look at the below for an example:

```
public class SessionFactory
{
    protected static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SessionFactory));

    //Several functions omitted for brevity

    public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        if(!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(GetSessionFactory()))
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(GetSessionFactory().OpenSession());

        return GetSessionFactory().GetCurrentSession();
    }

    public static void DisposeCurrentSession()
    {
        ISession currentSession = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(GetSessionFactory());

        currentSession.Close();
        currentSession.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The key to the above is that whenever you retrieve your first session you bind it to whatever context you are using.